# Grails Fixtures + Build-Test-Data tries to create duplicate IDs for objects

Tags: hibernate, grails, fixtures

I'm trying to incorporate fixtures and build-test-data into our grails testing, yet even with the simplest example, I get an id collision when trying to build two of the same class with the build-test-data plugin. I can't help but feel like I'm missing something very simple.

This works just fine. Assume everything that needs to be imported is imported.

```
class TemporaryFixturesTests extends GroovyTestCase {

/* injected */
def fixtureLoader

void testFixtureLoadsProperly() {

    def fixture = fixtureLoader.load {
        build {
            testCompany(Company, name: "TestCompany")
            testBasicUser(User, username: "TestUserBasic", company: testCompany)
        }
    }

    assert fixture.testBasicUser.company.name == "TestCompany"
}

void setUp() {
    //TODO
}
}
```

Yet this one...

```
class TemporaryFixturesTests extends GroovyTestCase {

/* injected */
def fixtureLoader

void testFixtureLoadsProperly() {

    def fixture = fixtureLoader.load {
        build {
            testCompany(Company, name: "TestCompany")
            testCompany2(Company, name: "TestCompany2")
            testBasicUser(User, username: "TestUserBasic", company: testCompany)
            testBasicUser2(User, username: "TestUserBasic2", company: testCompany2)
        }
    }

    assert fixture.testBasicUser.company.name == "TestCompany"
    assert fixture.testBasicUser2.company.name == "TestCompany2"
}

void setUp() {
    //TODO
}
}
```

breaks with the error...

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the   same identifier value was already associated with the session: [<path removed>.Company#0]
```

This leads me to believe that build-test-data is trying to associate id0 to both companies. That stinks. Can anyone tell me why?

--Edit--

It seems the tables in question are not set up to have auto-incrementing ids. So when build test data tries to make me an id column, it makes 0s every time as that is an automatically generated integer.

osborp provided the solution for this.  Build a TestDataConfig with :

testDataConfig {

```
sampleData {
    '<path removed>.Company' {
        def i = 0
        id = {-> i++ }
    }
    '<path removed>.User' {
        def i = 0
        id = {-> i++ }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The exact test case works **flawless** for me. I have latest version of fixture and build test data plugin and am using Grails 2.2.2.

```
//Domain classes:
class User {
    String username
    Company company
}

class Company {
    String name
}
```

Build test data never stank for me. My approach to a problem seldom does. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a [TestDataConfig.groovy](https://github.com/tednaleid/build-test-data/wiki/TestDataConfig) file? You can use this to create values dynamically to avoid unique constraints.

Comment: I have not. This may be what I'm looking for. But shouldn't build-test-data work auto increment ids on its own?

Comment: Yep. That was it! I just added 'def i = 0 id = {-> i++ }' to that file and bam. Fixed. Thank you!

Comment: IDs should auto increment (I've never had to do anything additional when using Fixtures/BuildTestData before). Your test case works for me too. Maybe your db config differs somehow. (For info I used: Grails 2.2.2 using the in-memory db, Fixtures 1.2 and BuildTestData 2.0.5)